# XLabs initializing services Android

Tags: xamarin.forms, xlabs

I install nuget packages in my project and all works fine. But if I try to inherit the MainActivity from the XFormsApplicationDroid class, then I get an exception:

[image]

I also do not know what to do with ToolBar and TabBar.

Comment: Please note that the XLabs components are outdated and no longer being maintained. If you possibly can, switch to something else.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I want to get a Device service. Do you know the analog?

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't know what you mean by 'Device service'